# How to change this code in vb.net to show just the time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

how to convert this code in vb.net to show only time instead of date and time in vb.net

```
            Dim UTCTime As Date = Date.UtcNow
            Dim IndianTime As DateTime = UTCTime.AddHours(5.5)
            TextBox1.Text = IndianTime
```

Comment: in asp.net , you have to format Textbox1.Text = IndianTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss")

Comment: add .ToString("T") to the datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a format specifier in ToString() eg:

```
IndianTime.ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

Should output the Time only (in 12 hour clock, with AM or PM).

More examples of custom formatting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), and there's a very [useful list of Date Time format patterns with examples here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm).

Whole thing:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim UTCTime As DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow
    Dim IndianTime As DateTime = UTCTime.AddHours(5.5)
    TextBox1.Text = IndianTime.ToString("hh:mm tt")
    TextBox2.Text = Now.ToString("hh:mm tt")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim UTCTime As Date = Date.UtcNow
Dim IndianTime As DateTime = UTCTime.AddHours(5.5)
TextBox1.Text = IndianTime.ToString("T")
TextBox2.Text = Now.ToString("T")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TextBox1.Text = IndianTime.ToString("hh:mm") 'For 12 hr format
TextBox1.Text = IndianTime.ToString("HH:mm") 'For 24 hr format
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim formatString As String = String.Format("{0,HH:mm:ss}", IndianTime)
```

[String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) reference

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
    Dim UTCTime As Date = Date.UtcNow
    Dim IndianTime As DateTime = String.Format("{0:hh:mm}", UTCTime.AddHours(5.5))
    TextBox1.Text = IndianTime
    TextBox2.Text = Now
```